# I want to protect my videos with temporary urls. How can i do that?

Tags: php, url, signed, pre-signed-url

I'm publishing videos from my own server on my own website and to protect the videos i want to secure the urls. I saw some urls has token, id etc. Those urls expires after a certain time. I want to secure my video urls, so anyone has the url could access and download the video in a certain time, after time passes the url will not be accessable. Also if its possible i want to publish the videos on my website with the same process.

Answer (score 1):

Store a unique hash + expire date in database. Provide the hash as GET parameter to the script which gives out the data. In this script, check the hash + expiration date before sending data.